# How to store values in JSON with Spring sessions and Redis?

Tags: java, node.js, spring, redis

Spring sessions with Redis managment by default stores session values as Java serialized objects, namely `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`. But I need instead of serialized object store this data in JSON for getting session data in Node.js server. Is it possible? How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

When you define a bean like this (note method name), spring will use it to serialize session data.

```
@Bean
public RedisSerializer<Object> springSessionDefaultRedisSerializer() {
    return new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class);
}
```